# Elegant way to compare each value in 2 sorted integer lists using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to find the best way to compare values in 2 integer lists and return the list as soon as I find value in one list is bigger than the other

**`[1,2,3] and [1,2,4]`**

return second list [1,2] are equal but 4 in second list is greater than 3 in first list

`[4,2,3] and [1,5,6]`

return first list because the 4 in first list is greater than 1 in second list. No need to check other elements.

Now I can use a loop here but I am sure there is a better way using Linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two lists are the same length, you can find the first element that's not equal using LINQ:

```
    var firstDifference = array1.Zip(array2, (a,b) => (a,b))
         .SkipWhile(x => x.a == x.b).FirstOrDefault();
```

After that it's easy to handle the three cases: `default`, `a<b`, `a>b`.

Edit: To handle these three cases you could do:

```
    int firstDifference = array1.Zip(array2, (a,b) => (a,b))
         .SkipWhile(x => x.a == x.b)
         .Select(x => x.a.CompareTo(x.b))    // -1 or +1
         .FirstOrDefault();                  // 0 if no elements
```

This gives 0, -1 or +1 because `default(int)` is `0`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. There is a small gotcha though. The value returned by this function will be Tuple(int, a, int b) and since Tuple are value types and not reference types you cant check for null so you will have to check for if (!firstDifference .Equals(default)) { your code here}``

Comment: @Abhi.Net You could consider returning `new { a, b }` instead of `(a, b)` which would be a reference type instead of a value type.

Comment: You could do `var firstDifference = array1.Zip(array2, (a,b) => (a,b)).SkipWhile(x => x.a == x.b).Select(x => x.a.CompareTo(x.b)).FirstOrDefault();` to get -1, 0 and 1 as the result.

Comment: @Olivier Rogier This is actually the right solution for my problem. array1.Zip(array2, (a,b) => (a,b)) means that parameter a is from array 1 and b is from array 2. I can use this in an If-else statement to execute my logic.  For context, the two lists represent 2  set of cards and they are sorted from large to small. The problem required me to compare elements at each index and return as soon as I found. So in your example (ignore the order) [4,2,3] and [1,5,4] 4 is the right answer and I dont need to compare further.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Eh? It _does_ indicate which list it is: -1 for one list and +1 for the other list.  It's trivial to add an if statement to return list a or b depending on that value.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution does not answer the OP question as it was written, and results with the select added, that answer the question, are false.

Comment: Op says it does answer the Q, but if you really need to see the extra, obvious one line to get the list from the value here it is: `return firstDifference < 0 ? b : firstDifference > 0 : a : null;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple solution, I am considering that list can be null and of different length.

```
public static List<int> GetBiggerList(List<int> ls1, List<int> ls2)
{
    if (ls1 == null)
        return ls2;
    if (ls2 == null)
        return ls2;

    int length = Math.Min(ls1.Count, ls2.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (ls1[i] > ls2[i])
            return ls1;
        if (ls2[i] > ls2[i])
            return ls2;
    }

    if (ls1.Count > ls2.Count)
        return ls1;

    return ls2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Without Linq*

```
static int[] Compare(int[] list1, int[] list2)
{
  if ( list1 == null && list2 == null ) return null;
  if ( list1 == null ) return list2;
  if ( list2 == null ) return list1;
  for ( int index = 0; index < list1.Length && index < list2.Length; index++ )
  {
    int compareValue = list1[index].CompareTo(list2[index]);
    if (compareValue == 0) continue;
    if (compareValue > 0) return list1;
    return list2;
  }
  int compareLength = list1.Length.CompareTo(list2.Length);
  if ( compareLength == 0 ) return null;
  if ( compareLength > 0 ) return list1;
  return list2;
}
```

*Test*

```
var list1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 4 };

var list3 = new int[] { 4, 2, 3 };
var list4 = new int[] { 1, 5, 6 };

var list5 = new int[] { 1, 2 };

Action<int[]> print = list =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(list == null ? "Same" : string.Join(",", list));
};

print(Compare(list1, list2));
print(Compare(list3, list4));
print(Compare(list1, list5));
print(Compare(list5, list1));
print(Compare(list1, list1));
print(Compare(null, list1));
print(Compare(list1, null));
print(Compare(new int[0], list1));
print(Compare(list1, new int[0]));
```

*Output*

```
1,2,4
4,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
Same
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```